# How to solve PHP Error installing Composer on CentOS7

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7, yum

When I run `sudo yum install composer` on CentOS7 I get this error

```
Error: Package: composer-1.8.4-1.el7.noarch (epel)
   Requires: php-zip
   Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
       php-zip
   Available: php-pecl-zip-1.15.3-1.el7.remi.7.0.x86_64 (remi-php70)
   Available: php72w-common-7.2.16-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
       php-zip
   Installed: php-common-7.3.4-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php73)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.0.33-5.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.0.33-7.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.1.27-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.1.28-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.2.16-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.2.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
       Not found
   Available: php-common-7.3.3-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
       Not found
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What I've tried that haven't worked:
I've tried running `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`, 
I've tried running `--skip-broken` after the yum install, 
I have re-installed php, 
I have cleaned yum.

Here is what my `php -v` looks like

```
[centos@localhost etc]$ php -v
PHP 7.3.4 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2019 13:48:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.4, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

php centos-7 yum composer

Comment: on centos I usualy just do https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: try yum install php-pecl-zip.x86_64 or yum install php-pecl-zip or similar

Comment: You've installed PHP from a 3rd party repo; if that repo doesn't provide a composer package then follow the advice from @Bram

Answer (score 2):

You have  multiple providers for PHP. which create conflicts, you should only use one.

- disable webtatic
- keep only one of remi-php7x

Run

```
yum-config-manager --disable webtatic
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php70
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php71
yum-config-manager --disable remi-php72
```

Then you will be able to use PHP 7.3 and any extension

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
yum install php-zip
```

and to install composer of other tools from the repository.

```
yum install composer
```

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)